# ExtJS 4.1: Another way to load ExtJS Application for production

Tags: extjs, loading, production

I was wondering if it's possible to include all the components that we needs like JAVA import without including the ext-all.js at the index file. My problem is that even if ext-all.js is minified, my application is still loading slowly (Production mode) and I think that I'm not using all the features in this file.

So, if someone know how to do that, it will be very useful for me and my app! :)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Sencha Cmd?

This tool can search your application for the needed classes (your own and the ExtJS ones) and merge them into one file.

Never got this tool working, but if you're using the MVC from ExtJS, it should work for you.

http://www.sencha.com/blog/all-new-sencha-cmd

Comment: I've already choosen this way but I've got some errors when I use this command => sencha -sdk /path/to/extjs generate app MyApp /path/to/app!This is the error:   Failed to determine framework name.  Please ensure this command was issued from either a framework or application directory!... I followed the documentation but I'm still getting this error!

Comment: tried the `sencha compile` command? This should work with non-standard apps, too: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_app_single .... with some `<!-- <x-compile> -->` and `<!-- <x-bootstrap> -->` tags I even got a filled all-classes.js. but at the moment I got some problems with syncRequires(),which I needed in the pre-compile version, but not in the compiled one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and keep you informed! :)

Comment: You need to run that command from WITHIN the SDK folder (or a folder generated by Sencha Cmd). Look for the hidden .sencha folder - that should tell you if you're in the right place or not.

Comment: Thanks guys!It works!The problem is the Extjs version!... Another problems, I see many java error when I generate the app => [ERR] at many java exception error!Is it normal or I did something wrong?

Comment: I don't get any Java exceptions. Everything seems to work fine, when compiling, just the end-result is not working.

Comment: But the command that I've run, generate a new app architecture with its dependencies!I need a command for an existing app!The command will search within each files (within app folder) and extract needed classes!What command should I use in this situation!In my root folder, I've the ExtJs SDK + index file + app folder

Comment: I used something like this: `sencha compile -classpath=app.js,app,ext/src page -in=app.html -out=build/index.html`

Comment: No, like I said: I don't get errors, I just end up with an `all_classes.js` where most of my classes are missing.

Comment: Thanks!it begins to improve but this error persists: Failed to resolve dependency Object for file Ext.ux.ToolbarDropp! Have you ever faced it?

Comment: No, but I read about the `Ext.ux` stuff. It's not "normally" in an ExtJS distribution and you have to copy it from the samples. Since the classpath only says `ext/src` it probably is missing...

Comment: I removed some files from ux folder and I think it was working because in the end, the console show something like this `[INF]Concatenating output to file C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Bureau\TestSenchaCmd\MyApp\extjs\build\all-classes.js`.I haven't seen any errors but some warning [WRN] ECMA-262 from Yui Compressor. It generates all-classes.js like hte console said!But the file is empty. :(

Comment: EDIT: I've already put the `!-- <x-compile> --> <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->` tags in my index file!

Comment: It works!I didn't know that we have to move at the app folder!..So it generates all-classes.js and the all needed class concatened!I hope that I can rely on this class!Thank you very much for your help! :)